# Number of elements in a set of nth roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am confused about number of nth roots of unity because I know that set of nth roots of unity is a finite abelian group but somewhere I read for some n ,this is infinite group. Please tell me about these cases and whether n belongs to $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z$

Comment: *"somewhere I read for some n ,this is infinite group"* I doubt that. The set of $n$th roots of unity has $n$ elements. It is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_n:=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. They are examples of *cyclic groups*, and there is one other example of a cyclic group, namely the infinite cyclic group $\Bbb Z$ (which is not isomorphic to any group of roots of unity).

Comment: Where did you read that? In that case $n$ is not rational number I think...(also can not use the term "$n$-th root of unity")

Comment: I read that for Set G = { x: x is a nth root of unity for some n € N } , ( G , . ) is an infinite group . Please explain why?

Comment: "Some n" is very different from $n$th roots for a fixed $n$.

Comment: Please tell me how these fixed n and some n differs?

Comment: Showing that $G$ forms a group is trivial. We show that a subset of $G$ has cardinality $|\Bbb N|$. We have $G=\{e^{2\pi i k/n}\mid n\in\Bbb N~\land~k=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. Setting $k=1$, we have $\forall~n,m\geq 2~(n\neq m)$ that $e^{2\pi i/m}\neq e^{2\pi i/n}$. This trivially follows from the injectivity of $\cos$ on $[0,\pi]$. So, for $n\geq 2$, the elements of the set $K=\{e^{2\pi i/n}\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ are pairwise distinct, hence $|K|=|\Bbb N|$. Since $K\subset G$, we conclude that $G$ is an infinite group.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear from your phrasing which of these two cases you are talking about.

**Case 1.** For a particular $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider the set of $n^\text{th}$ roots of unity under the operation of multiplication. This forms an abelian group with $n$ elements. For example, if $n = 4$, then you have the finite (four element) abelian group $\{1, -1, i, -i\}$ under multiplication.

**Case 2.** Consider the set of all roots of unity under the operation of multiplication. Again, this forms a group, but it has infinitely many elements. (It includes the first root of unity, the second roots of unity, the third roots of unity, etc.; essentially, it is the union of all such groups as described in the first case.)

Comment: So benjamin sir, it means  for Set S={ union of all sets C}  (S ,.) is an infinite abelian group where C ={ x : x is a nth root of unity for n€ N} ? Am I correct

Comment: @user472602 You have just described **Case 2** in your preceding comment.

Comment: I think I have used your both cases to describe infinite abelian group (S,.). and Sir I want to confirm that whether I concluded correct or not?

Comment: So benjamin sir, it means for Set S={ union of all sets C} (S ,.) is an infinite abelian group where C ={ x : x is a nth root of unity for n€ N} ? Is there need any correction sir or am I right

Answer (score -1):

The n-th roots of unity are best understood using the polar form of complex numbers and the exponential function. The n-th roots are $e^{2\pi ik/n}$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq k<n$. Geometrically these are the points of a regular n-gon on the unit circle in the complex plane with $1$ as a fixed point. From the polar form we can see that multiplying two of them together will add the $k_1$ and $k_2$ components together, and reducing them modulo $n$ will give us the polar form of another n-th root of unity. Because the multiplication of complex numbers is commutative, $1$ is a member of the n-th roots and $e^{2\pi i/n}$ generates the group it is an cyclic group of order $n$. There is no $n$ for which this is an infinite group.

However the entire unit circle in the complex plane forms a group and the n-th roots are a subgroup. I can also construct a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ by taking an irrational number $q$ and generating the group with $e^{2\pi iq}$ and it's inverse. Maybe these are the infinite cases you've heard about.

Comment: ok sir ,now I got it